# CPQ Generate Document Apex Jobs Queued Status

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, cpq, heroku

When clicking on "Generate Document" -> "Save" within a Quote record. The screen gets stuck loading. I did notice within Apex Jobs there is a lot of jobs Queued.

[image]

[image: List of Queued Apex Jobs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had to do with a performance problem over with Heroku. CPQ services hosted on Heroku were negatively impacted resulting in the loading screen and queued jobs. The issue resolved itself once the Heroku servers were back to full health (4 hours).